# DevExtreme set default sort values

Tags: javascript, devextreme

Is possible set default sorting values in DevExtreme grid over one specific column?

In this Example i have two columns. One Column has disable filtering. For example at second column, which i want to filtering i have values 1,2,3. On load document i need show to user only values 1,2 and user can set value 3 if he want.

This is my code:

```
   this.grid = {
                        dataSource: this.dataSource,
                        columns: [                        
                            {
                           dataField: "OneColumn",
                           allowFiltering: false
                        }, 
"SecondColumn"],
                        sorting: {
                            mode: "multiple"
                        },
                        headerFilter: {
                            visible: true
                        },
                        hoverStateEnabled: true,
                        searchPanel: {
                            visible: true
                        }, selection: {
                            mode: "single"
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, please elaborate and explain, is it custom sorting or custom filtering you want ?

Comment: Hi i want custom filtering. Answer nex (column.filterValues) is that what i need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `column.filterValues` option to predefine the header filter value. Here [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tw0dn8b4/) that demonstrates it in action